# Django Form not saving to MySQL

Tags: django-forms

Hello and Thank you in advance:

I have a form that is not saving the input data into the MySQL database.  I am not getting an error, it simply isn't saving that data...

```
My Model:

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class DraftInput(models.Model):
    player_id = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.player_id

class DraftInputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DraftInput
```

My View:

```
def player_draft_input_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DraftInputForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/draft/')

    else:
        form = DraftInputForm()

    return render_to_response('baseball/basic_draft_pick.html', { 'form': form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Basic Draft Pick Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Draft" />
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

I bet this is something really simple and I am going to kick myself, but I have been looking at this code for about 5 hours now...

Thank you,

dp

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Have you confirmed that the form is filled out and the is_valid branch runs? We need to track down if the problem is between the form and the view or the view and the db. Do any of your other forms save to the db correctly?

Comment: I commented out the is_valid branch and there wasn't a change in behavior.  I am not getting any errors on the django-toolbar.  This is the only form I have created so far.  I am a newbie, so I am not sure how best to troubleshoot to see what is happening.

Comment: It sounds like your form isn't valid because your page isn't following your redirect to /draft/ (btw, check out the url and reverse() docs instead of hard coding redirects). Anyway - add print statements everywhere to see what is actually happening with your code -- verify the request is coming in as POST, verify the form is valid (doesn't seem to be), maybe add an else to that if valid and print out the form fields. Something isn't right and you get to go exploring to find out what it is.

Comment: Thank you!  I will start exploring...

Comment: Actually, it is redirecting to the /draft/ page.  I am still troubleshooting...

Comment: @Keeyai I figured it out...see below.----THANK YOU!!!----

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something I was just missing!  in the code above:

```
return render_to_response('baseball/basic_draft_pick.html', { 'form': form, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

should be:

```
return render_to_response('baseball/basic_draft_pick.html', { 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

no comma after { 'form': form }

I feel stupid, but gratified that *I* caught the error and not someone else...

Thank you all!!

dp